# Trumbowyg Widget (django) stopped working

Tags: python, django, trumbowyg

While using Trumbowyg django widget (Django FS Trumbowyg https://bitbucket.org/fogstream/django-fs-trumbowyg/), it suddenly stopped working, and the form falls back to a [text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBS4z.png).

I can't seem to find a reason for it to stop working as I don't think I have changed anything related to it, except changed the inheriting template slightly to load jQuery sooner. I also tried to reinstall the PIP package, and manually sync the local static and the static cdn folder to both contain the fs_trumbowyg resources.

With all this said, it seems like the server is successfully serving the browser the resources as seen below.

`[05/Jul/2016 11:31:35] "GET /static/fs_trumbowyg/css/trumbowyg.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Jul/2016 11:31:35] "GET /static/fs_trumbowyg/trumbowyg/design/css/trumbowyg.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Jul/2016 11:31:35] "GET /static/fs_trumbowyg/trumbowyg/trumbowyg.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Jul/2016 11:31:35] "GET /static/fs_trumbowyg/trumbowyg/langs/ru.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Jul/2016 11:31:35] "GET /static/fs_trumbowyg/js/trumbowyg.upload.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0`

And when inspecting the text-box element it seems to correctly think it's the trumbowyg text-box `<textarea class="trumbowygwidget form-control" cols="40" id="id_content" name="content" rows="10"></textarea>`

However, it still renders it as a normal text-field.

My question is about how I may go about resolving it as I'm, as a result of the past few hours, running out of ideas.

EDIT (to show how Trumbowyg is set up):

forms.py (the form file):

```
from trumbowyg.widgets import TrumbowygWidget

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  content = forms.CharField(widget=TrumbowygWidget)
  ...
  class Meta:
    ...
    fields = [
      ...
      "content",
      ...
    ]
```

In the settings.py file I have `'trumbowyg',` inside the INSTALLED_APPS array.

I have also, per instruction, added the line `url(r'^trumbowyg/', include('trumbowyg.urls'))` inside the (global) urls.py file.

Comment: trumbowyg tag has had about ten posts over the past yer, two of them appear to be from you. Can you outline the problem, what you expected and what you got and give some code samples

Comment: @e4c5 Actually, the other question seems to be mis-tagged. Anyway, I have updated the question with codesamples of how I have installed the widget.

The problems, as the question describes, is while the server seems to send the browser the assets, the browser doesn't render the widget.

Comment: Apparently, Trumbowyg doesn't work when you load a version of Jquery that's greater than 2 before you let Trumbowyg load its own version which is 1.7.x.